# How to prevent recompile for ad hoc query

Tags: sql-server, caching, sql-execution-plan

When I first run the following query, a recompile occurs taking (7s).  If I run it again results come back in <100ms.  However when I only change the numeric value, it insists on doing another recompile each time.

Is there a way to prevent recompile without resorting to wrapping it with an SP (which was already validated to work)?

```
set statistics time on;

declare
    @o bigint = 3374707

select * from ComplexTableValuedFunction(@o)
option (keep plan, use hint ('DISABLE_PARAMETER_SNIFFING')) -- has no effect in ad hoc?

set statistics time off;
```

Side issue: The statistics messages only lists the short execution time (~100ms) and never the compile time for some reason.  SQL Sentry verifies the compile time is ~7s.

Comment: Cached execution plans are cache keyed on the combination of two things: (1) the hash of the query statement and (2) the current @@OPTIONS. Since you're changing the hash of the statement by changing the number, even just a single digit, the new statement will require compilation and potential caching. The way to avoid (most of) that is to place the select statement itself inside a Table-Valued User-Defined Function or a Stored Procedure. It then gets its own plan, and the ad-hoc portion of your statement will be compiled quickly and cached seperately.

Comment: So what is *ComplexView* here, it's not an actual view because of the parameter so must already be a TVF?

Comment: @stu, yes it is a TVF that internally joins a number of views.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, Your statement about using TVF does not seem to be true.  I tried it literally and parameterizing it like so:  declare
    @o bigint = 3374710;
select * from Pub.IsoPropertyValueView2(@o, null);
First run always takes 2s to compile then subsequent runs take 100ms.  Changing the parameter value goes back up to 2s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time an ad-hoc batch changes, even by a single character, it is recompiled.

To prevent a recompile, you need to pass the batch through using `sp_executesql`, and properly parameterize it. At this point, you will get parameter sniffing, unless you add the hint `'DISABLE_PARAMETER_SNIFFING'`

```sql
set statistics time on;

EXEC sp_executesql
  N'
select * from ComplexTableValuedFunction(@o);
',
  N'@o bigint',
  @o = 3374707;

set statistics time off;
```

The actual `EXEC` statement does not have a query plan, so changing the value will not affect anything.

Note that a parameterized query from a client app such as C#/SqlClient actually uses `sp_executesql` anyway.

Comment: You only need a hint if you want to prevent parameter sniffing, which may or may not be a good thing. Note that a parameterized query from a client app such as C#/SqlClient actually uses `sp_executesql` anyway.

Comment: Are you sure this is true for C# EF Framework when selecting from a view?  When I capture DB commands to the debugger I just see a parameterized select statement (also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70188276/538763).  When I run the parameterized SQL manually from an editor, it seems to recompile as well whenever I change the value of the parameter.  I guess that might be your point about sp_exeuctesql being required.

Comment: EF does parameterize properly via SqlClient, and I believe the trace output will show `exec sp_executesql` so you are not doing the same thing as it (client apps use a special RPC command to call procedures, but the effect is the same: `sp_executesql` is itself a procedure).